# Crashlytics: "Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x... :: NSOperation 0x..." - EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: nsoperationqueue, dealloc, crashlytics

I got some crash reports in crashlytics which I don't understand at all, here's the crash log of the thread that crashed:

[image]

I don't find any hints to my code, nor is it something reproducable or only happening on specific devices. According to Crashlytics it's not a problem with RAM or disk space, so I'm really helpless here.

Does anyone have some hints with that stacktrace?

Comment: Looks pretty similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28595938/2446155)

Answer (score 2):

I have some thoughts:

1. The second line of the first row is the iOS way of saying what went wrong. It reads: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`. This is a `Bad access` error.
2. You're trying to `_dealloc` something, according to the stack trace listing a method, `[_queueForDealloc:]`. With iOS's ARC (Automatic Resource Counting) system, things in Xcode can't call `alloc` or `release` because of it allocating memory and releasing it automatically. This technology was released with iOS 5.

My guess is, the compiler really doesn't like that `[_queueForDealloc:]` method you may have called, or you're trying to `dealloc` something that has already been `dealloc`'ed. (See the third line:  a call of `-[_PFArray dealloc]`.)

Either way, this is a bad access error. Check what you're deallocating and whether or not you should be deallocating it.

Comment: Now I'm seeing it was `CoreData` that called the `dealloc`'s. That looks more like a bug in ARC than anything.

Comment: hm... I don't like assuming it's a bug on Apples side; I really think I'm doing something wrong, should just have to know what

Comment: Try adding debug logs with `NSLog()` to see where it is and paste the code as an edit to your question.